# How to create a view to encrypt a BLOB column in DB2?

Tags: encryption, view, db2

I am trying to create a view to transparently handle encryption of a BLOB column.  I am using the approach described [here](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/data/library/techarticle/0210rielau/0210rielau.html#section4b).

**Background**

> *NOTE*
>
> There was a comment by @tc, asking why
>   I am trying to encrypt this, since the
>   encryption key is then stored (in
>   plain text) in the code.  I have a
>   requirement to encrypt the data
>   at-rest. Since the application needs
>   to be able to encrypt and decrypt the
>   data, without human intervention, the
>   key needs to be stored somewhere. This
>   way, it is stored in the application,
>   which is on a different server from
>   the database. This approach seems to
>   appease the compliance folks, but I am
>   open to other suggestions.

So, here is my table definition (I am using `$` as the statement termination character):

```
CREATE TABLE fileAttachmentEncrypted (
    work_item_id integer NOT NULL,
    fileName varchar(100) NOT NULL,
    documentType varchar(100) NOT NULL,
    contentType varchar(100) NOT NULL,
    fileImage BLOB(104857600) NOT NULL, 
    last_update_by varchar(20) NOT NULL,
    last_update timestamp NOT NULL
)$
```

This table creation statement executes cleanly.

Then, I try to create my view:

```
CREATE VIEW decryptedFileAttachment AS 
SELECT work_item_id, fileName, documentType, contentType, 
        DECRYPT_BIT(fileImage, 'SUPERSECRETPASSWORD', 'REMINDER'), 
        last_update_by, last_update FROM fileAttachmentEncrypted$
```

**Problem**

This results in the following error:

```
Error: DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-440, SQLSTATE=42884, SQLERRMC=DECRYPT_BIT;FUNCTION, DRIVER=3.50.152
SQLState:  42884
ErrorCode: -440
Error occured in:
CREATE VIEW decryptedFileAttachment AS 
SELECT work_item_id, fileName, documentType, contentType, DECRYPT_BIT(fileImage, 'SUPERSECRETPASSWORD', 'REMINDER'), last_update_by, last_update FROM fileAttachmentEncrypted
```

**What I know so far**

According to the [DB2 documentation](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/html/as400/v4r5/ic2924/index.htm?info/db2/rbafymstnegcodes.htm), this means

> SQL0440   SQLCODE -440   SQLSTATE 42884
>
> Explanation: Number of arguments on
>   CALL must match procedure.

However, I am not really sure what that means.  I tried omitting the password hint as well as the password (setting it for the session using `SET ENCRYPTION PASSWORD`) for the `DECRYPT_BIT` call.

One theory I have is that my table definition should not be using a BLOB column.  Most of the examples online showing how to implement column-level encryption in DB2 use `VARCHAR FOR BIT DATA` as the column type that holds the encrypted value.  In fact, the [DB2 documentation says to use this](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/dzichelp/v2r2/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.db29.doc.admin/db2z_definecolencryption.htm):

> When data is encrypted, it is stored
>   as a binary data string. Therefore,
>   encrypted data should be stored in
>   columns that are defined as VARCHAR
>   FOR BIT DATA.

However, VARCHAR columns are [limited to 32,740 bytes](http://www-12.lotus.com/ldd/doc/lei/701/lccon.nsf/b3266a3c17f9bb7085256b870069c0a9/8de5e6309d591116852570a700668cb3?OpenDocument).  The data that I need to encrypt will be much larger.

On the other hand, [this documentation](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/data/library/techarticle/dm-0711mohan/index.html) implies that `BLOB` is a perfectly cromulent column type for holding encrypted data:

> DECRYPT_BINARY: The DECRYPT_BINARY
>   function accepts as its first argument
>   an encrypted_data large object of type
>   BLOB or CLOB. You must specify a
>   password as its second argument,
>   unless the SET ENCRYPTION statement
>   has specified as the default for this
>   session the same password by which the
>   first argument was encrypted.

Is this theory correct?  Is something else going on here?  How can I encrypt my BLOB column?  Has anyone else in the SO community implemented column-level encryption in DB2? Were you able to do it on a BLOB column?

Comment: Why are you "encrypting" a column and then storing the key in your source code?

Comment: I have a requirement to encrypt the data at-rest.  Since the application needs to be able to encrypt and decrypt the data, without human intervention, the key needs to be stored somewhere.  This way, it is stored in the application, which is on a different server from the database.  This approach seems to appease the compliance folks, but I am open to other suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

You should probably take a look at the [IBM Database Encryption Expert](http://www-01.ibm.com/software/data/optim/database-encryption-expert/). The encrypt/decrypt functions you are looking at are really not meant for security applications.

Second viable option could be developing [external routines](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v9r7/topic/com.ibm.db2.luw.apdv.routines.doc/doc/c0020569.html) for managing the encryption and decryption of data. Probably that is cheaper but requires some actual development and knowledge about both DB2 and cryptography.